# How to retrieve the text entered in texbox inside datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a textbox inside a datagrid in a cellediting template. I want to bind the text
entered in the textbox to textblock each cell. I tried this code but it will not worked.

Here is my xaml:

```
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <!--<ComboBox x:Name="monday" Width="50"   IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true"   Loaded="monday_Loaded" SelectionChanged="monday_SelectionChanged"></ComboBox>-->
                            <ComboBox x:Name="monday" Width="30"   ItemsSource="{Binding  Path=Subjects}" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCollectionItem,Mode=TwoWay}"     Loaded="monday_Loaded" SelectionChanged="monday_SelectionChanged"></ComboBox>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="staff" Width="30"  ItemsSource="{Binding  Path=mondstaff}"  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCollectionItem1,Mode=TwoWay}"  Loaded="staff_Loaded" SelectionChanged="staff_SelectionChanged"></ComboBox>
                            <TextBox x:Name="monothers" Visibility="Hidden" Text="{Binding  Path=Subjects}" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" SelectedText ="{Binding SelectedCollectionItem2,Mode=TwoWay}"   Width="30" TextChanged="monothers_TextChanged"></TextBox>
                            <!--<ComboBox x:Name="staff" Width="50" Loaded="staff_Loaded"></ComboBox>-->
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
```

Here is my code:

```
public string SelectedCollectionItem
        {
            get { return _SelectedCollectionItem; }
            set
            {
                _SelectedCollectionItem = value;
                RaiseProperty2("SelectedCollectionItem2");
            }
        }
```

If anyone knows how to do it, kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed this code in your code-behind

```
public void monothers_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var binding = ((TextBox)sender).).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
   binding.UpdateSource();
}
```

More details

see this discussion

[How to hookup TextBox's TextChanged event and Command in order to use MVVM pattern in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491510/how-to-hookup-textboxs-textchanged-event-and-command-in-order-to-use-mvvm-patte)

and also you need to refer this blog

[Make a Silverlight TextBox update its binding on every character with a Behavior](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/vbandi/archive/2009/12/24/make-a-silverlight-textbox-update-its-binding-on-every-character.aspx)