# WPF MVVM textbox text binding vs changedText event

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, binding, command

I have textbox with Text property binded to viewmodel.
I have binded TextChanged event to viewmodel.

But the problem is that the event fires every sign is added to textbox(that's good) and Text in viewmodel is refreshed when textbox lost focus(that's bad for me).

How to make this Text property refreshing after each sign?

Or how to send sender as parameter? I think sender would have resfreshed data.

My interactivity xaml:

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
    <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
        <helpers:CustomCommandInvoker Command="{Binding UnlockChangedCommand}"   />
     </interactivity:EventTrigger>
 </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I'm using RelayCommand.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There is a really simple answer to this; use UpdatePropertyTrigger=PropertyChanged. This will update your VM property each time a character is changed. No need for triggers or commands :-)

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ViewModelProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
```

Read here for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Binding is pretty nice, I can't help to fall back to old working methods (event handlers etc..) seems so logical when I read this now.. thanks

Comment: According to Microsoft Documentation, using UpdateSoruceTrigger inside a textbox can diminish performance, be careful when using this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Data_Binding_UpdateSourceTrigger